# In-memory database for mahout recommendatiion

Tags: mysql, mahout, in-memory-database, mahout-recommender

I have been working on mahout lately. The current version of supports inputs from Files, MySQL etc... via its DataModels. In my case, the raw-data resides within a Postgres DB at a client location. The raw-data requires a good amount of pre-processing before being fed into the mahout DataModel. Currently I'm storing the refined data as a simple `*.csv` file and loading it to Mahout using inbuilt FileDataModel.

Is it possible to use an inmemory DB to actually store the refined data and t load it to Mahout using its existing `MySQLJDBCDataModel/JDBCDataModel`? . If so, what kind of inmemory DB would serve this purpose

Answer (score 0):

sqllite3 is quite often the goto in memory database and for good reason it's one of the most battle hardened databases out there and can be found literally everywhere. The browser you're using is likely using it. It has an in memory option that's fairly straight forward. Even disk based it's also fast.

Most databases given enough RAM will efficiently load most of your data into RAM anyway. I used PostgreSQL as the backend for a search engine for a long time and most access was to RAM with almost nothing going to disk when reading. If you already have the database in PostgreSQL it might be simpler to keep it in that.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you can only access an SQLite in-memory database from a single process.

If you need the ultimate performance, even a fully cached persistent database won't be as fast as a true in-memory database system.  To me, though, it doesn't sound like you need that level of extreme performance.